# Which is the best tool to create report for accessibility testing?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, report, accessibility

I want to prepare a accessibility report for web application. Which tools should I use?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very opinion based question and really depends on what you mean by report. There are lots of paid services that can give you detailed PDFs with reports, whereas the free services tend to be in-app reports or raw data. These are some free services (may have paid versions) that I use regularly (in no particular order).

1. Google Chrome Dev Tools Accessibility Audit - great for number score
2. https://tenon.io - good printable report with raw data too.
3. http://wave.webaim.org - good interactive reporting (not printer friendly).
4. Axe Chrome Plugin and Axe-Core - good set of rules (Chrome Audit uses them too) and the CLI tools are great
5. SiteImprove Accessibility Chrome Plugin - great for breakdown by WCAG Acceptance Level.

You can look at https://a11yproject.com/resources for other tools and resources

Answer (score 0):

Here https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tools/, you will find information about all available tools to test accessibility of your web or mobile application. If privacy is the concern for your application, many freeware options available too and listed on the link provided above.

You need to select the tool based on the requirement to test accessibility against which accessibility standards e.g. WCAG 2.0 - Level A, Level AA, Level AAA, HTML 5 recommendation, US section 508.

In general, we must check our web application against accessibility standards - WCAG 2.0 (Level AA) and US Section 508.

Below listed free tools are easy to install and provide good reporting.

1. **The A11Y Machine**: https://github.com/liip/TheA11yMachine - Provide accessibility report(against the accessibility standards you opted for) of single web page and complete website too!
2. **The A11Y Project:** https://a11yproject.com/
3. **pa11y**: https://github.com/pa11y/pa11y
4. **paypal/AATT**: https://github.com/paypal/AATT